# Android custom Javadoc task throws "Path may not be null or empty string"

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, javadoc

When running my Javadoc task (see config below), an error is thrown with this message: `Cause: path may not be null or empty string. path = ''`. This error only started occuring after I updated the Android Gradle Plugin from 8.0.2 to 8.1.0. Other posts mention that this error is looking for a keystore file and/or for the `RELEASE_STORE_FILE` property in `gradle.properties`. This property is currently not in my `gradle.properties` since I do not intend to use it anyway. Is this keystore file also necessary for debug builds and why is it only occuring after the AGP update?

My Javadoc task in the `build.gradle`:

```
dependsOn "generateReleaseRFile"
dependsOn "compileReleaseKotlin"
failOnError true
configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)
source = android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
classpath += configurations.implementation
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include you execute for "running my Javadoc task".

Comment: I am seeing the same error. The issue seems to be the usage of `android.getBootClasspath()` . That is retuning an empty string, hence the error. As far as what the replacement of that is, I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround to get it to work. It seems `android.getBootClasspath()` always returns an empty array. You need to use `project.android.getBootClasspath()` now instead. The caveat here is that that method won't return a populated list until after the configuration stage. So, you'll need to add an `afterEvaluate` block and then set the classpath for your task in there:

```
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.myJavadocTask.classpath += files(project.android.getBootClasspath())
}
```